# It's always making logout everytime i make an action

Tags: magento2, logout

Every time I login with my account on the website an tries to make an action it will logout.

Example:
I will go to the login page and insert the username and password, and it redirects me to my info-account page. But if I go to the products page, contacts page or shopping cart page and come back to the account page, it will always logout.

There is an exception: for instance if I go to the "about us" page or terms and conditions page and come back, I will still be able to see my info account.

Comment: Please check the list of 3rd party extension. Might be Page header is reset for products page, contacts page or shooping cart page.

Comment: Any exceptions in the logs? Using anything non standard for session data?